# How to add method to objects in meteor js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I attach a new method to a collection object in meteorjs?

```
user = Meteor.user()
user.newMethod() // how/where do I attach this function?
```

Comment: Some related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007231/whats-the-best-way-to-attach-behavior-to-a-meteor-collection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270517/is-there-a-nice-way-to-wrap-each-meteor-user-in-an-object-with-prototype-functio

Answer (score 3):

The thing is `Meteor.user()` returns the result of something like `Meteor.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});` so you have to redefine the entire method because there's no prototype object.

Client js, Server js or both:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.user = function() {
       var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});

       if(!user) return null;

       _.extend(user, {   // Lodash method https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign
           newMethod: function() {
              //Do something
           },
           newMethod1: function() {
              //Do something
           }
       });

       return user;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
user = Meteor.user();
user.newMethod = function () {
  // Do something
};
```

and later on

```
user.newMethod();
```